# Who is Gog of the land of Magog mentioned in Ezekiel Chapters 38 amd 39

Tags: revelation, prophecy, ezekiel

Ezekiel 38 (NET Bible)

A Prophecy Against Gog

> 38 The Lord’s message came to me: 2 “Son of man, turn toward[a] Gog,
>   of the land of Magog, the chief prince of Meshech and Tubal.[d]
>   Prophesy against him

Comment: start with this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gog_and_Magog

Comment: Answer is too long to explore on this board.  Short answer: it was Vespasian, the "prince" who led the Roman legions that had been stationed in the lands ruled by the Roman empire of the 1st century AD during the 2nd destruction of Jerusalem, which lands were known by Ezekiel under their Persian names.  See Parts V-VIII of Ezekiel In Revelation at my blog ShreddingTheVeil.org for all parameters that surround and define the Gog of Magog prophesy.

Comment: Gina   God said that he would give Gog   " as food to all kinds of birds of prey" (Ezekiel  39:4 NASB) " "You will fall on the mountains of Israel, you and all your troops and the peoples who are with you; I will give you as food to every kind of predatory bird and beast of the field." Also, read Ezekiel 39:11 NASB.   I do not know the history of the time, but were any of the above prophesies  fulfilled on Vespasian and his troops

Comment: @Ozzie - sorry for the late response - The phrase " fall on the mountains of Israel" was a euphemism for standing against God.  I address this in the last post of the series on Gog of Magog at my blog https://shreddingtheveil.org/2020/07/14/ezekiel-in-revelation-part-viii-on-the-mountains-of-israel/.  And, in that light the answer is yes.  All of the enemies of God fall on His mountain, which is His kingdom.  All who stand against His kingdom fall, just as Vespasian, Titus, and all of pagan Rome did. The problem w/ solving this prophesy is that everyone tries to make everything literal.

Comment: @Gina it cannot have been Vespasian because the text says that Persia will be among the attacking armies, and Persia did not attack with Vespasian.

Comment: @aefrs - The Persian names were the ones Ezekiel knew.  The same land areas were called by different names when they were conquered by the ancient Roman empire. Explained at https://shreddingtheveil.org/2020/03/29/ezekiel-in-revelation-part-vi-the-land-of-gog/

Comment: Gina We are told that at the end of the 1,000 years, Satan will be released from the abyss, and “he will go out to mislead those nations in the four corners of the earth, Gog and Magog, to gather them together for the war.” (Rev. 20:8) The Bible also speaks of the attack by “the king of the north” and of the attack by “the kings of the earth.” (Ezek. 38:2, 10-13; Dan. 11:40, 44, 45; Rev. 17:14; 19:19)  The scriptures tell us that all the nations of the earth will be involved in this final attack that prompts the war of Armageddon.​Rev. 16:14, 16. I believe that it is the same attack

Comment: @Gina We know where Persia is to this day. Persia did not attack with Vespasian. These are some basic facts. Also these nations are not Persian names, they are the names of nations from Genesis.

Comment: @OzzieOzzie This is not true. Satan is not an enemy of G-d. Gog and Magog are not two separate nations, but rather Gog is the king of Magog. What do you even mean by "who is Gog" Gog is just a person. When we know who Gog is, that question won't need to be asked. This "book of revelation" has already been proven to be phony. The attack of Gog; however, is near the end of days.

Comment: @aefrrs - The post I linked shows that the nations / lands of the Ezekiel prophesy are the same lands called by other names that were part of the Roman empire.  If you will not go look at the evidence presented at the post, what can I say?  The Roman empire controlled the territory of the old Persian empire during the 1st cent. AD !

Comment: @OzzieOzzie - the book of Rev is NOT phony.  The current teaching about what Rev says is absolutely phony.  The entire book has been lifted out of context by Premillennial Dispensationalism and other similar dogma.  Put it back in context of the "soon" and "at hand" time of the 1st cent. AD and you find that it was the prophesy of the 2nd destruction of Jerusalem, which was the same prophesy of Ezek. Gog of Magog 2nd destruction of Jerusalem.  Revelation is legit.

Comment: @Gina you are clearly ignoring a basic fact. Persia is supposed to attack along with the other places. The website even mentions that Persia didn't attack.

Answer (score 1):

Among other possibilities, [Gog and Magog — Modern Apocalypticism — Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gog_and_Magog#Modern_apocalypticism) suggests that Gog and Magog correspond to the current Russian and Chinese people.
For instance, "*US President George W. Bush, in the prelude to the 2003 Invasion of Iraq, Bush told French President Jacques Chirac, 'Gog and Magog are at work in the Middle East.'*".

But that association isn't recent: "*In fact, Gog and Magog were held by the Mongol to be their ancestors, at least by some segment of the population.
As traveler and Friar Riccoldo da Monte di Croce put it in c. 1291, 'They say themselves that they are descended from Gog and Magog: and on this account they are called Mogoli, as if from a corruption of Magogoli'.*".

Today, there are various publications (not generally accepted by historians) promoting this view.
Here is one example:

> Scholars generally agree that “Gog” is Russia, and that “the land of Magog” includes China.
> The descendants of Meshech and Tubal have been found together throughout history.
> In Assyrian and Greek histories, Meshech appears as Musku, Muski or Mushki—all names related to the Russian spelling of Moscow, as you can read in the International Standard Bible Encyclopedia.
> What about Tubal? On the eastern side of the Ural Mountains lies the city of Tobolsk, named after the Tobol River, a name derived from Tubal.
> Tobolsk was once the seat of Russian government over Siberia and was basically considered Russia’s Asian capital.
>
> There is also a name for all of the Russian people in Ezekiel 38:2.
> There is controversy over how the Hebrew word rosh should be translated in this verse.
> The King James Version uses the adjective “chief.” But the correct rendering (used by the Moffatt, New King James and others) uses the word not as an adjective, but as a proper noun: Rosh.
> Thus, that verse should read, “the prince of Rosh, Meshech and Tubal.”
>
> Rosh was the ancient name of Russia, once called Rus.
> Many encyclopedias and commentaries (such as the Jamieson, Fausset and Brown Commentary) recognize this.
> So who is this “prince” of Russia, Moscow and Tobolsk? The use of all three names shows that this is an individual ruler of all the peoples of Russia, from the west to the east.
> The reference to the cities of Moscow and Tobolsk helps us see how vast Russian territory is in these latter days.
> — [theTrumpet.com - World News, Economics and Analysis Based on Bible Prophecy](https://www.thetrumpet.com/literature/14430-the-prophesied-prince-of-russia/print)

Comment: I have made some comments to Gina above you may wish to read them.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Gyges and the Gigantes. Magog is India (Land of Nod)

Chief prince is probably a corruption of Tiras

Answer (score 0):

We do not exactly know who Gog is. That is to be revealed near the end of days. What we do know is that Gog is the king of the land of Magog. This land is named after the person Magog in Genesis 10:2 who is a son of Japheth. Thus Magog is somewhere in Eurasia. Gog is supposed to come from a place in the far north as it says in Ezekiel 39:2. Furthermore, Gog is supposed to have a lot of power over Meshekh and Tuval (one of these is likely Turkey) and he is supposed to attack Israel along with the armies of Meshekh, Tuval (one of these is likely Turkey), Persia (Iran), Cush (Ethiopia), and Put.

Comment: aefrrs : I have made some comments to Gina above you may wish to read them.

Comment: @OzzieOzzie Gog is a person and we don't know his identity yet. One day it will be known.

Comment: aeffrs: Rev 20: 7-8 tells us that Satan will be released after the thousand years and will mislead the nations of the earth-"Gog and Magog" that prompts the war of Armageddon. God said that he would give Gog " as food to all kinds of birds of prey" (Ezekiel 39:4 NASB)

Comment: @OzzieOzzie I don't care what "revelation" says, I was answering a question about Ezekiel. Satan is just the chief prosecuting Angel, so how would he be released? He is not imprisoned. He does what G-d wants him to do.